# How do I connect to an SQLite database using PDO?

Tags: php, sqlite

I have an SQLite database and am trying to connect to it with PHP.
However, I get this error:

> **Warning: `sqlite_open()` [function.sqlite-open]: file is encrypted or is not a database in `C:\xampp\htdocs\deepthi\combadd\combadd_db.php` on line 4**
> Connection to database failed!

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi @user, welcome to SO.  I *strongly* recommend you use PDO - it's really easy, flexible, and more secure than whatever you (or I) will come up with by yourself (ourselves).  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try to use PDO instead of sqlite_open:

```
$dir = 'sqlite:/[YOUR-PATH]/combadd.sqlite';
$dbh  = new PDO($dir);
$query =  "SELECT * FROM combo_calcs WHERE options='easy'";
foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row)
{
    echo $row[0];
}
$dbh = null; //This is how you close a PDO connection
```

Comment: it was amazing Antonio. i need to insert data from excel sheet into sqlite using php. can you please help me? thanks

Comment: You'll find some examples here: http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/php-pdo-sqlite3-example/. Also, you should consider using a framework to help doing those repetitive tasks like connecting to a database, insert, update, delete records. Take a look at Laravel: http://four.laravel.com/

Comment: do i need to install that one to read xls data from php code

Comment: I think you can use this library: https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/.

Comment: http://php-drops.blogspot.in/2011/04/read-excel-sheet-xls-file-with-php.html i am trying to use reader.php will it work?

Comment: How can I add `PRAGMA` to this query?

Comment: Added `$dbh = null;` to close PDO connection.

Comment: " sqlite: "

at the begining on address is very important

Answer (score 10):

**Connecting To Database**
Following PHP code shows how to connect to an existing database. If database does not exist, then it will be created and finally a database object will be returned.

```
<?php
   class MyDB extends SQLite3
   {
      function __construct()
      {
         $this->open('combadd.sqlite');
      }
   }
   $db = new MyDB();
   if(!$db){
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {
      echo "Opened database successfully\n";
   }
?>
```

Now let's run above program to create our database test.db in the current directory. You can change your path as per your requirement. If database is successfully created then it will give following message:

```
Open database successfully
```

**SELECT Operation**

Following PHP program shows how we can fetch and display records

```
<?php
   class MyDB extends SQLite3
   {
      function __construct()
      {
         $this->open('combadd.sqlite');
      }
   }
   $db = new MyDB();
   if(!$db){
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {
      echo "Opened database successfully\n";
   }

   $sql =<<<EOF
      SELECT * FROM combo_calcs WHERE options='easy';
EOF;

   $ret = $db->query($sql);
   while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
      echo "ID = ". $row['ID'] . "\n";
   }
   echo "Operation done successfully\n";
   $db->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

    if ($db = sqlite_open('sampleDB', 0666, $sqliteerror) ) { 
        $result = sqlite_query($db, 'select bar from foo');
        var_dump(sqlite_fetch_array($result) ); 
    } else {
        die($sqliteerror);
    }

?>
```

Make sure sqlite support is enable, check phpinfo()

One another solution to your problem is:
Using sqlite3 module instead

```
class DB extends SQLite3
{
        function __construct( $file )
        {
            $this->open( $file );
        }
}

$db = new DB( 'sampleDB.sqlite' );
```