# Connect to an SQLite database with PHP

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

With the reference of the bellow link,I was tried to connect with an sqlite database using PHP.

[How do I connect to an SQLite database with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728265/how-do-i-connect-to-an-sqlite-database-with-php)

```
<?php
$dir = 'sqlite:/var/www/html/shijin/brandz_db';
$dbh  = new PDO($dir) or die("cannot open the database");
```

But i am getting the following error,

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not
>   find driver' in /var/www/html/shijin/sqlite.php:3 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/shijin/sqlite.php(3):
>   PDO->__construct('sqlite:/var/www...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/html/shijin/sqlite.php on line 3

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the PDO sqlite driver. Try

```
sudo pecl install pdo
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlite
```

Comment: I am using ubuntu,getting error sudo: pecl: command not found

Comment: Then I guess `sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite3` should do :P

Comment: @techouse I have tried ,but  Unable to locate package php5-sqlite3

Comment: According to http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php pecl have to be used on PHP  >= 5.4 so depending on version you might have to first install pecl and try installing if from there if suggestion from @techouse didn't work